# Change of Culture formatings in difrent devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-localization

I Have an asp.net core 3.1 MVC web application and I am using this code to generate localized Date strings

`StartDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR"))`

where StartDate is of type `DateTime`

this generates `1399/08/30` in my local matchin

but generates `2020/11/20` in the matchin where I deploy it *(I wil call it server)*.

does it have any problem with the server cultuer
or a problem with the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` in the server.

and I want the format whitch goes in my local matchin.

Comment: Whats behind StartDate? Model? Where are you getting wrong value? In view?

Comment: @Adlorem well yes behind StartDate is a Model but its not important. and I am calling this in view and it returns the strings I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try invariant culture

Comment: Why should I try that I say I want the print in fa-IR culture

Answer (score 0):

Well Actully there is two solutions for this.

one: Install windows server 2016 R2. because it have fa-IR culture.

two: make a Hand made date Converter wich I made it with this:

```
public static string ToPersianDateString(DateTime? date)
    {
        if (date==null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        var pc = new PersianCalendar();
        return pc.GetYear(date.Value) + "/" + pc.GetMonth(date.Value).ToString("D2") + "/" + pc.GetDayOfMonth(date.Value).ToString("D2");
    }
```

well it is some sort of mess but it works inthe situation wich U don't want to upgrade your OS.